# Handling bulk creation of models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, crud

I cannot find a good answer to this question anywhere. Consider the scenario where you have several security questions/answers for a user. These are the typical question/answers that one might see when requesting his password through a forgot password form or something similar.

The answers are modeled as SecurityAnswer, and they are associated with a user and a question (the question are static in the database, so the user can choose from a pre-defined list of questions).

When a user registers, he or she will choose several security questions and answer them. I am designing a REST API for this functionality... but doing this the standard REST way will require a request for each answer. What I'd like to do is send all of the answers with 1 request, but this isn't RESTful.

To make it RESTful, I've made a SecurityAnswersHashController which is in charge of performing CRUD actions on a group of answers. Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested attributes in your user model for the answers. This way, when you create a user you can also send the answers attributes and create all models in a single call.